# Hide file path and only display the file name

Tags: c#, combobox, filepath

I am working in C#. I have a segment of code that returns the file as well as path of a specific file type and places them inside a select list

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only get .sde files  
        string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files", "*.sde");
        this.GetSdePath.Items.AddRange(dirs);
    }
```

When I run my program, the select list contains all the sde files. They are listed/displayed as such:

c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files\NewCreated.sde
c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files\Inventory.sde
c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files\Surplus.sde
c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files\Logistics.sde

I am wondering if in my select list is it possible to hide the path and just display the name of the sde file. So the list would look like

NewCreated.sde
Inventory.sde
Surplus.sde
Logistics.sde

BUT, each value in the list would return the full path and name.
Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) on the sequence returned to apply the [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method that extracts just the filename from the fullpath

```
var dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files", "*.sde")
                              .Select (d => Path.GetFileName(d));
this.GetSdePath.Items.AddRange(dirs.ToArray());
```

I don't know how many files are present in your folder but probably it is better to use  [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of GetFiles

```
var dirs = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files", "*.sde")
                              .Select (d => Path.GetFileName(d));
```

MSDN says

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

**EDIT**
Following your comments below the choice of EnumerateFiles is not possible (available from NET 4.0) and if you want to keep the full path name available for other tasks but show just the filename in the listbox then you need to keep it in some kind of collection (an array or better a list)

```
 using System.IO;
 ...

 string sourcePath = @"c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files";
 List<string> dirs = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.sde")
                              .Select (d => Path.GetFileName(d)
                              .ToList());
 this.GetSdePath.Items.AddRange(dirs.ToArray());
                              ;
```

Make `List<string>dirs` a form level variable if you need its content outside the Form_Load event

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I believe I have the same issue as my comment below. I am using Framework 3.5. I'm looking at MSDN to see if I can revamp your code for my framework.

Comment: I was able to get your code to work. My only problem is that in order for my program to work it has to take the entire path of the file, including the file name. So it would have to take "C:\Users\JohnDoe\my_files\Surplus.sde" to work (Total inconvenience, I know). I used a message box to return the value and it just showed me "Surplus.sde". I may have to concatenate this value with the path. More importantly is that the select list (comboBox) is showing just the names though. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: If you want to keep the full path name available for other tasks but show just the filename in the listbox then you need to keep it in some kind of collection (an array or better a list) The variable should be a global if you need this info outside the Form_Load event or just a local one.

Comment: If using NET 3.5 then you can't use EnumerateFiles because it is available from the 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path.GetFileName(string path)`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only get .sde files  
        string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\my_files", "*.sde");
        this.GetSdePath.Items.AddRange(dirs.Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: I thank you so much for your post. I am using .NET Framework 3.5. I think my framework may not be compatible with your example as some of the keywords are not coming up in the Intellisense, i.e. Path.GetFileName. I know, I should "upgrade" soon. I'm looking at MSDN to see if I can revamp your code for my framework.

Comment: Well I was also missing "using system.io". Added that in but am not able to get the code working. Getting some errors. (1)Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])' has some invalid arguments ....(2) Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char[]>' to 'object[]'